# relation between files table and books table laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, pivot-table

I have some migrations books,users,categories,authors and files

i made a pivot table for books and files,"book_file" table:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('book_files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('book_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('file_id');

            $table->foreign('book_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('books')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');


            $table->foreign('file_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('files')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and Book model code:

```
public function files(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(File::class,'files','book_files');
    }
```

File model code:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];



    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
    }
```

BookController:

```
    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $authors = Author::all();
        $files= File::all();
        return view('books.create', compact('categories','authors','files'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,
            [
                'name'=>'required|string|max:256',
                'pages'=>'required|integer|numeric',
                'ISBN'=>'required|string|numeric',
                'price'=>'required|integer|numeric',
                'published_at'=>'required|date|date',
                'file'=>'required',

            ]
        );


        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $filename = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file->storeAs('public', $filename);
            $file = new File;
            $file->name = $filename;

            $file->save();

        }

            $book =  Auth::User()->books()->create($request->except('_token'));
        $book->categories()->attach($request->get('category_id'));
        $book->authors()->attach($request->get('author_id'));
        $book->files()->attach($request->get('file_id'));
        return redirect('/books');
    }
```

files uploading in database works true but my pivot table (book_file) doesn't change! what is wrong?
I am beginner in laravel,please help,thanks.

Comment: you have `function books` in your model user when you call on this `Auth::User()->books()`

Comment: A pivot table like the one you've created would most commonly be used for multiple belongsToMany() or hasMany() relationships. Try changing the books() function on the File model to this: return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class); and see if that makes them sync. Then you will need to use the "sync" function instead of "attach". See if this works. I know it's not the exact relationship you think it should be, but you are using a DB structure that's expecting it.

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos Yes, i have it in my code but i didn't write it here because it was too long and my problem is relation between books and files table no user or other tabels.

Comment: With that said, you may want to just set things up the "proper" way for your relationship as you initially intended it. In this case, you would want the File relationship to stay belongsTo() and you would move the book_id column directly to the files table, not in its own many-to-many pivot table.

Comment: @eResourcesInc I changed belongsTo to beongsToMany and also changed attach to sync but I received this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'file_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `file_id` from `files` where `book_files` = 41)

Comment: I can't see all of your code, but that looks like something is not right in your models/relationships. A many-to-many relationship with both models using belongsToMany() certainly works with a pivot table like the one you have shown. It's just too hard for me to troubleshoot the exact cause of the problem from the code provided. That said, it seems to me like you are using a many-to-many pivot table when a simple many-to-one relationship would suffice.

Comment: @eResourcesInc  You mean that ;using book_id in files table and at all dosen't use book_file table?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your comment, but what I'm saying is that you don't need to have a book_file table at all. You could simply set this up so that the files table has a book_id column. Then you would always know which book a file belongs to by calling $file->book. Inversely, you would know which files belong to a book by calling $book->files. This would scan the files table for any files that have a book_id corresponding to the current book. No many-to-many pivot table would be needed, but you could still get it to work if you really wanted to by using my suggestions above.

Comment: @eResourcesInc Yes,I agree with you that something not right in my code :/ . Anyway I used your way and now I don't have problem but in next step i will be sure It's really true or not.thank you for your help :)